# Error Using EasyXLS Library

Tags: php, excel

After installing the EasyXLS library to read .xlsb documents with php. I come across this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'COM' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\Acessando arquivo XLSB\readerxlsb.php:2 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Acessando arquivo XLSB\readerxlsb.php on line 2

This is the code:

```html
<?php
$xls = new COM("EasyXLS.ExcelDocument");
$rows = $xls->easy_ReadXLSBActiveSheet_AsList("Dashboard.xlsb");
for ($row1=0; $row1<$rows->size(); $row1++)
{
    $rowLine = $rows->elementAt($row1);
        if ($row1 == 2) {
            $column1[6]."<br>";
            $valor1 = $row->elementAt(6);
        }
}
?>
```

Is there a specific place I owe this library so that it recognizes the 'COM' class?

Comment: PHP should recognise [COM](http://php.net/com) automatically if it's installed so my guess is that you haven't installed it. `EasyXLS` has nothing to do with PHP, you're just using a .NET library from PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error does not come because EasyXLS library is not in a specific place. 
It is related to `COM technology in .NET` extension in PHP server. You need to activate this extension.

The following link will explain you how to do it:
https://www.easyxls.com/manual/troubleshooting/class-com-not-found.html

Also restart IIS Server or the web server that you use:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635851(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: Did not work. Sorry for the delay, I just had time to get it now. :/

Comment: did you restart iis?

Comment: No. How do I do it ?!

Comment: I updated my answer. But if meanwhile you already restarted the machine, this step is no longer necessary